# Troubleshoot Redirect Loop affecting only Mobile Devices

Tags: iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I'm using IIS10 and URL-Rewrite and for some reason my website has a redirect-loop but ONLY on mobile devices. No matter which mobile, what network it's connected on or how many times I clear cache, the site won't load on any browser for any mobile device. I've tested using iphone, android, chrome, firefox, safari it's all the same.

Here are my rule(s) in the web.config

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)\.example\.com$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I have other websites hosted on the same machine with similar URL rewrite rules that work fine no problems.

**Even with all my rules turned OFF, I'm still getting a redirect loop on mobile.**

Any tools, tips/tricks on how to troubleshoot this would be most appreciated!

---

UPDATE: Info from Fiddler

**RAW:**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://example.com/
X-Redirect-Reason: Wrong Portal Alias Requested
Set-Cookie: dnn_IsMobile=True; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: language=en-US; path=/; HttpOnly
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 13:19:56 GMT
Content-Length: 142

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://example.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

**Headers:**

```
**Response Headers**
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
**Cache**
Cache-Control: private
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 13:19:56 GMT
**Cookies/Login**
Set-Cookie: dnn_IsMobile=True; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: language=en-US; path=/; HttpOnly
**Entity**
Content-Length: 142
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
**Miscellaneous**
X-Redirect-Reason: Wrong Portal Alias Requested
**Security**
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
**Transport**
Location: http://example.com/
```

I see `Wrong Portal Alias Requested` but not sure what would cause that?

Comment: Try to open private browser tab on your test mobile device, as your previous attempts might be cached and lead to such issues.

Comment: Hi Lex, i've done this already on different devices connected to my router & on cellular network. I've also had other people in different locations test on their devices & networks and it's the same result.

Comment: Then you have to use a tool like Fiddler to capture the actual traffic of the mobile browser, https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS and then see from it anything strange.

Comment: could you please share your site bindings? did you set any other code on your site for redirection? what kind of certificate you are using?  did you apply this rule at the server level or site level? could you please share your failed request tracing result?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I will post the failed request tracing results shortly, there's no other code that is redirecting, the SSL is a wildcard SSL, and I have many bindings on the website I will create some examples to show you.

Comment: @LexLi I've updated the question with some Fiddler Data, lmk if theres other areas I should be looking at for now the main issue I see from this is `Wrong Portal Alias Requested` I'm looking into that now.

Comment: You are running a special web app DNN, which you didn’t even mention in the question body. Check its documentation and analyse its redirection code. There isn’t much left on IIS that you need to check I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to LexLi who got me looking in the right direction. Fiddler was very helpful.

Yes, the website is constructed on the DNN CMS application, the problem was that in DNN there is a table `portalsettings` that has a setting called `DefaultPortalAlias` there was a wrong value in this setting.

Additionally in DNN's `PortalAlias` table there are `bit` fields for `IsPrimary` and there the `IsPrimary` in my case was set to the `www.` version of the alias not the `non-www.` and in IIS my url rewrite canonical rule was point to the `non-www.` binding, this is what caused the loop. I'm not sure why it was only affecting mobile but it's working now after those changes.

Thanks @Lex Li for the insights!